# Compiling 32 bit GLIBC - Missing object is circular reference

Tags: gcc

On CentOS 6.4 64-bit system I am trying to build a 32-bit version of GLIBC (2.18).  Using yum I installed a 32-bit version of the GCC library in /lib.  I use a directory named GLIBC32 for my build. After trial and research I settled on these options:

--prefix=/usr/local/lib32 --exec-prefix=/usr/local/bin32 --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu CC="gcc -m32" CXX="gxx -m32"

A lot of the build is successful except it seems that SUNRPC components need objects (crt1.o) and libraries being created by the build. If I had the GLIBC library objects SUNRPC wants I wouldn't need to build the library!!!!

****If I stop and copy crt1.o into /lib, then the build complains about libc.so.  ANY SUGGESTIONS APPRECIATED. THANKS****

gcc -m32 /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_main.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_hout.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_cout.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_parse.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_scan.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_util.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_svcout.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_clntout.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_tblout.o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpc_sample.o  -o /home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpcgen
/usr/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/oracle/tmp/glibc32/sunrpc/cross-rpcgen] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/oracle/tmp/glibc-2.18/sunrpc'
make[1]: *** [sunrpc/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/oracle/tmp/glibc-2.18'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Here are the contents of /lib

[oracle@qawebtech glibc32]$ ls -l /lib
total 156
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Oct 18 19:53 alsa
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     14 Oct 18 19:53 cpp -> ../usr/bin/cpp
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Oct 18 19:57 crda
drwxr-xr-x. 43 root root   4096 Oct 18 20:21 firmware
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root   4096 Oct 18 19:56 kbd
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 120672 Feb 21  2013 libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     28 Oct 26 00:39 libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Oct 18 19:57 lsb
dr-xr-xr-x.  4 root root   4096 Oct 18 20:20 modules
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Feb 21  2013 security
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root   4096 Oct 18 19:52 terminfo
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root   4096 Oct 26 03:49 udev

Answer (score 0):

There is another less painful way to obtain the 32 bit libraries for Centos 6.4. You can download the i386 RPMs from the Centos repository (http://mirror.centos.org).  Then use rpm to install them into a new root.  Once you have the library files, move them into /lib and your 32 bit app will be able to find them. You might have to manually repair some links.  See this link for details about downloading RPMs into a new root.

[How to build a chroot jail for Centos](http://geek.co.il/2010/03/14/how-to-build-a-chroot-jail-environment-for-centos)

GLIBC is not really set up to be built on an already existing system unless you are cross-compiling.